# Overriding bootstrap variables doesn't seem to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to override he column widths in bootstrap. As suggested in bootstrap_and_overrides.less, this is where I'm supposed to override them:

```
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html for their names and documentation
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;
 @gridColumnWidth : 55px;
 @gridGutterWidth: 43px;
```

When I restart the server and reload the page, the css generated does not change and the span widths remain unchanged.

Do I need to recompile the less file in order for the change to be effective? How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org) to recompile in order to see your changes. Either use the JavaScript from the LESS site, or one of the methods on the [Twitter Bootstrap page about LESS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#compiling).

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize your download of bootstrap here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html.

`@gridColumnWidth` and `@gridGutterWidth` are available to be customized.